# HyperLedger for IoT

Tags: blockchains

Which HyperLedger version is more suited for IoT devices with power/memory constraints (Arduino-like)?
In particular, is there a lightweight implementation of HyperLedger Fabric?

To be more precise on the power/memory constraints, you can take [Particle Photon](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/p/particle-industries/photon-mcu-wi-fi-modules)  as a reference (1 Mb Flash, 128 Kb ram).

Comment: How power/memory constrained are you? Which is more important? What kind of processing power do you have? *IoT devices* are a very wide range of devices. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the IBM blockchain platform. It can be developed in a quick, easy-to-use local environment created to help you build your blockchain skills. Those are quite lightweight toolkits that leverages open source Hyperledger tools and includes everything we need to code. We can test it locally and they can also be deployed on the IBM Cloud.

The following link will be helpful: https://www.ibm.com/blockchain/getting-started.html

Comment: This is not really answering the original question.